# Infinite loop while trying to print numbers 1 to 10 in assembly x86 64 bits

Tags: assembly, x86-64

i'm new programming in ISA x86 64 bits, so i'm trying to print the numbers 1 to 10 in assembly using a conversion in hexadecimal, but I get an infinite loop cause the 8 bit register **$cl** can't increment. I've been using **gdb** to analyze the code but I dont find a way to run my code and dont have a infinite loop in the process. I hope y'all can help me, and remember and new into this so bear with me please.

```
section .data
    number db 0; Buffer 
    nl db 10; \n

section .text
    global _start

    _start:
        ; syscall information
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, number
        mov rdi, 1

        mov byte[number], "0" ; Inicializando the buffer in "0" = 46 Dec 

        .loop:

            add byte[number], cl ; cl contains the data of the number in ASCII format
            mov rdx, 1 ; lenght of bytes
            syscall

            inc cl; ASCII data

            cmp cl, 0x39; 0x39 = 57 Dec = 9

            jle .loop; lower equal jump

        ; \n
        mov rsi, nl
        mov rdx, 1
        syscall

        ; Exit
        mov rax, 60
        xor rdi, rdi
        syscall
```

I've been using the gdb to analyze the code, even I tried to change the 8 bit register instead of using **cl**, but nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

`syscall` destroys `rcx` which includes `cl`. Pick a different register. `rax` is used for the return value so that needs to be reloaded as well, although in this case it happens to work. Also, you are always adding to `number` which won't do what you want.
A possible solution with minimal changes:

```
section .data
    number db 0; Buffer 
    nl db 10; \n

section .text
    global _start

    _start:
        ; syscall information
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, number
        mov rdi, 1

        mov bl, '0'

        .loop:

            mov [number], bl ; bl contains the data of the number in ASCII format
            mov eax, 1 ; need to reload syscall number
            mov rdx, 1 ; lenght of bytes
            syscall

            inc bl; ASCII data
            cmp bl, 0x39; 0x39 = 57 Dec = 9

            jle .loop; lower equal jump

        ; \n
        mov rsi, nl
        mov rdx, 1
        syscall

        ; Exit
        mov rax, 60
        xor rdi, rdi
        syscall
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jester, as I can see, the usage of pointers in assembly are too important, imma try to keep learning, and again thanks for u answer.